# PHP Simple HTML DOM getting two different cell classes (inline) but one may be empty

Tags: php, dom, simple-html-dom

Okay I searched all over for this and tried many things (3 hours) but, I am still stumped.

Here is my HTML snippet from somepage.com.

```
<table class="infotable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="185">
    <tr>
        <td class="what"">First name:</td>
        <td class="whatdet">Jim</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="what">Last name:</td>
        <td class="whatdet">Bo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="what">Age:</td>
        <td class="whatdet"></td> <!--PROBLEM IS HERE WITH EMPTY CELL-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="what">Sex:</td>
        <td class="whatdet">Rarely</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="what">City:</td>
        <td class="whatdet"></td> <!--PROBLEM IS HERE WITH EMPTY CELL-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="what">State:</td>
        <td class="whatdet">California</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my Code snippet with a test with attempt to show me a little more info with isset line. (Yes, I am obviously clueless)

```
require_once 'simpledom/simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://somepage.com/');
$i=0;
$tabletitles = array(); /* Get the titles 'what' Cell Names */
$tabledetails = array(); /* Get the Details in 'whatdet' Cells */
$tables = $html->find('table[@class="infotable"]'); /* Where both reside in */

foreach($tables as $table) {
    $titles = $table->find('td[@class="what"]');
    $titlesd = $table->find('td[@class="whatdet"]');

    foreach($titles as $title)  {
        /*UPDATE NOTICED A PROBLEM WITH a character like $ so I added */
        /*will do the same in $titlesd if I can figure out how to get it  */

        $title1 = preg_replace('/([?#^&*()$\\/])/', '\\\\$1', $title);

        echo $title1; /*Changed from $title*/

        if (isset($titlesd[$i])) /*this is just for testing*/
            echo $titlesd[$i].' is either 0, empty, or not set at all';

        /* WHAT I WANT is echo '<tr><td>'. $title .'</td><td>'. $titlesd[$i] . </td></tr>;*/
        $i++;
    }
}
```

**What I am trying to attempt:**

```
------------|----------
First name  | Jim
----------- |---------
Last name   | Bo
----------- |---------
Age         |
----------- |---------
Sex         | Rarely
----------- |---------
City        |
----------- |---------
State       | California
----------- |---------
```

**But what I get now:**

```
------------|----------
First name  | Jim
----------- |---------
Last name   | Bo
----------- |---------
Age         | Rarely
----------- |---------
Sex         | California
----------- |---------
City        |
----------- |---------
State       | 
----------- |---------
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to assign a "blank" to `$titlesd[$i]` or skip it when it's in the loop. So, I keep getting undesired results. (to say the least)

So again, I beseech a guru here to give me another highly prized lesson.
Thank you..

Comment: I would grab each td within `$titlerow = $table->find('tr');` and then do a `foreach($titlerow as $title)  {`. Your current code doesn't assign `what` and `whatdet` to a particular row, that's your problem. I haven't tested this theory but it seems intuitively correct.

Comment: Could you tell my what you get from `echo count($titles).'/'; echo count($titlesd);` just after yours `->find('td...`

Comment: BTW; your REGEX is wrong : https://regex101.com/r/W9BX1y/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this is what you try to do :

```
require_once 'simpledom/simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://somepage.com/');

foreach($html->find('table[@class="infotable"]') as $table) {
    foreach($table->find('tr') as $line)  {
        $titles = $line->find('td[@class="what"]', 0);
        $titlesd = $line->find('td[@class="whatdet"]', 0);

        echo '<tr>'
                .'<td>'.htmlspecialchars($titles).'</td>'
                .'<td>'.htmlspecialchars($titlesd).'</td>'
            .'</tr>';
    }
}
```

I explain a bit :

- first, I go for `<tr>` lines, as it's what you want to print as output
- next, I try to get the first match ([index `0` as 2nd parameter with `->find()`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)) for both title and data on the current `<tr>` line
- and last, I print them with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to avoid problems with `&>'<"`

*nb: as `->find()` with index will return `NULL` if there is no find, I make this code assuming at worst `echo $titlesd` will be `NULL` and display nothing*

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$titlesd = ($table->find('td[@class="whatdet"]')) ? $table->find('td[@class="whatdet"]') : "";
```

Comment: Can't get that to work. It crashes.Crashes when I replace the '$titlesd=' line with your offering. I also replaced the 'echo $title' with the WHAT I WANT line. I also got rid of the "this is just for testing lines". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide detailed and complete answer: [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Blag's answer is good but it can be much simpler:

```
foreach($html->find('.infotable tr') as $tr){
  echo $tr->find('td.what',0)->text();
  echo $tr->find('td.whatdet',0)->text();
  echo "\n";
}
```